# Print the record as vertical result SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

How to show the result as vertical in SQL

i have an idea using **PIVOT** but i can't make it to work.

```
SELECT  '1' ID
      , 'Vincent' Name
      , 'Enteng' NickName
      , 'Male' Gender
```

Result is:

[image]

but i want the result to be

```
ID          1
Name        Vincent
NickName    Enteng
Gender      Male
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just dealing with one record, then use `union all`:

```
SELECT 'ID' as which, '1' as value union all
SELECT 'Name', 'Vincent' union all
SELECT 'NickName', 'Enteng' union all
SELECT 'Gender', 'Male'
```

Note in some databases, you might need `from dual` or even another construct.

Comment: So, do i have to write SELECT for each column result in my query? is there any way to do this in PIVOT?

Comment: You can do it using `unpivot` (if you are using SQL Server or Oracle).  But that won't be less typing.

Comment: Yeah but this one also isn't even less typing if i have lots of columns

Comment: Using `unpivot`, you have to list all the columns.  If that is an issue, then use a query to get them from meta data tables, such as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.